# debug http requests in chrome

Tags: html, image, debugging, google-chrome, resources

I'm using the developer window in google chrome, and it gives a lot of useful information. However, I have several resources (3 or 4 images) which are receiving 404 errors. These resources are unnecessary, so I need to find out why the browser is requesting them (what css/javascript/inline html is directing the request, so that I can remove that line of code. Is there a good way to find out why it was requested?

Comment: The most general solution to the problem would require a modification to the browser, hook up the functions and trace the origin (in case of malicious code). For a normal website, you can search the source code for the domain, and/or some part of the link in the DOM and in the scripts (using Firebug).

Comment: If the application you use to write your code let's you search in all files belonging to your project, why not just do it this way? Should only take a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools -> Developer Tools -> Network Tab

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use Firebug addon in Firefox. I haven't found any equivalent for Chrome extension. Firebug has "NET" tab you can see all the requests made to the server.

Comment: You've missed the point of the question entirely. Chrome's developer tools are largely analogous to Firebug.

Comment: Right, I use that too, the functionality is basically the same. However, I am at a loss to find out using either tool *why* the request was made.