# How it's chosen between calling done() or fail()?

Tags: jquery, callback

I have a script which does a GET request for authenticating an admin. 
It calls a python function which is able to recognize if the supplied credentials are valid or not and returns a HTTPResponse with 200 or 401 codes, respectively. (`return HttpResponse(status)`, where status is properly set)

The script simply shows an alert with "Success" or "Failure" if the admin is authenticated or not, but even when I provide  the wrong password - and the python function returns correctly the 401 code - I get the "Success" alert, i.e. it's called always the `done()` callback.

Can you explain this behaviour? How can a script distinguish if it has to call the `done()` or the `fail()` callback?

EDIT:

```
function logIn(){
var my_url="/admn/log/"+$("#password_field").val();
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: my_url
}).done(function(data) {
alert("Success!")
}).fail(function(data){
alert("Error!");
});
```

---

```
if pbkdf2_sha256.verify(kwargs["pwd"],expected_hash) == True:
#success
msg='Admin authenticated'
status=200 #Http success ok
else:
#failure   
msg='Authentication failed. Please check the password'
status=401 #Http client error unauthorized
credentials_file.close()
return HttpResponse(msg, status)
```

Comment: can you write your Ajax function . for more information

Comment: Have you verified the request status in browser dev tools network? Can also access it as property of `jQXHR` object in done() callback. Doesn't sound  like status is what you think it is

Comment: @charlietfl Can you please better explain what you mean?

Comment: How're you verifying that the returned response code is 401?

Comment: Can see the actual http status in dev tools network (F12)

Comment: I think that data corresponds to the response code returned by the python function. Probably I'm wrong, but I thought that done() callback was called on success (and so, 200 code) and fail() otherwise. For this reason, because I'm not sure about how this works, I wrote this question.

Comment: Please [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284903/debug-http-requests-in-chrome), and verify if the returned response code is really 401.

Comment: @31piy I checked it and you're right. Despite I set the response status code to 401, I get 200 as response to the GET request. Why? I'll edit my question adding the piece of my python code which returns the response.